# PHP - Getting data from hidden inputs with multiple square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, input

I have inherited some code which contains hidden inputs with multiple square brackets - example below:

```
<input name="myinput[1]['sausages'][2][]" type="hidden" />
<input name="myinput[1]['bacon'][1][]" type="hidden" />
<input name="myinput[2]['steak'][1][]" type="hidden" />
<input name="myinput[2]['mince'][2][]" type="hidden" />
```

The first value is referring to a 'type' field in the database, the second is the 'item' and the third is the 'order'

How can I extract this info using a for loop in php?

Comment: Well, you find the values as array inside the superglobal $_POST (or $_GET) and can either iterate through it or directly access elements in there. Try to dump those superglobals first to see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a for-each to travel

```
foreach($myinput as $temp)
{
    foreach($temp as $a)
    {
        echo $a;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

or if you want to read data using it's key use like this..,

```
foreach($myinput as $temp)
{
    echo $temp['type'];
    echo $temp['item'];
    echo $temp['order'];
    echo "\n";
}
```